# Kendo Multiselect not sending data to controller

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC, and I'm trying to make a page for creating and editing a certain view model, `ProjectVM`. The piece that I'm having trouble with is using a Kendo Multiselect to populate a List in `ProjectVM`. The list is of another model type, `Staff`. Here is the view model...

```
public class ProjectVM{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ... //more items
    public List<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different variants of this, such as making `Staff` an IEnumerable or an Array. Here is the editor page...

```
@model Site.Models.ProjectVM
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", Model, new AjaxOptions() {HttpMethod = "post" })){
    ...
    @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(M => m.Staff)
        .BindTo(new SelectList((System.Collection.IEnumerable)ViewData["Staff"], "ID", "FullName"))
        .Value(Model.Staff)
```

As you can surmise, when loading the page I store all the `Staff` items in ViewData. The above did not send any information from the multiselect at all to the controller, and in the received view model claimed that the size of the `Staff` list was 0, despite what I selected. I tried instead to get rid of the form and use an Ajax POST call...

```
function save(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "Save",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json", 
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ID: @Model.ID,
            ...
            Staff: $("#Staff").data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems(),
        })
    })
}
```

This garnered slight improvement, as the List received by the controller now showed the correct size. However, each entry was filled with blank information. The header of my controller code...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Save(ProjectVM vm){
    ... //vm has never been correct
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Everything I have researched has either not fit my scenario or not worked. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (a `<select multiple>` only submits an array of simple values) - the property you need to bind to needs to be `public IEnumerable<int> Staff { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like using **SelectListItem** for binding data to Kendo **MultiSelect**.

### Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Site.Models
{
    public class ProjectVM
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> AllStaffs { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> SelectedStaffs { get; set; }

        public ProjectVM()
        {
            AllStaffs = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectedStaffs = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Site.Models;

namespace Site.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Project
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var vm = new ProjectVM
            {
                AllStaffs = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "John Doe", Value = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Eric Newton", Value = "2"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "David Washington", Value = "3"},
                }
            };
            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(ProjectVM vm)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

### View

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model Site.Models.ProjectVM
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post" }))
    {

        @(Html.Kendo()
            .MultiSelectFor(m => m.SelectedStaffs)
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
              .BindTo(Model.AllStaffs))
        <button id="btnSave" type="button">Search</button>
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnSave").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Save",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    ID: @Model.ID,
                    SelectedStaffs: $("#SelectedStaffs").data("kendoMultiSelect").dataItems()
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Screen Shots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Took a little restructuring, but this worked like a charm. Win for the win.